# DOM. Why the class won't remove after I click on again

Tags: javascript, class, dom, toggle, addeventlistener

I tried to style some element by click on them by giving them a class. Only one that I click on will have the style. But if I click the element twice, the class won't remove. I use toggle, but still does not work

```js
const lists = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
lists.forEach(list => {
  list.addEventListener('click', () => {

    // remove the previous class active
    lists.forEach(list => list.classList.remove("active"))
    list.classList.toggle('active');

  });
});
```

```css
.list.active {
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
  <li class="list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
  <li class="list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
  <li class="list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: cant reproduce - code works fine above - perhaps your real code is not the same

Comment: Your code seems to be working, can you please create a [mre]

Comment: oh, did you meant the others DONT have the class removed ... `lists.forEach(list => list.classList.remove())` - what does that remove - compared to `lists.forEach(list => list.classList.remove('active'))`

Comment: your `.classList.remove()`  dosn't specify any class to remove. -> `.classList.remove('active')`

Comment: @Bravo. The code was wrong. I've just updated it

Comment: so, now it works - what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. your `.classList.remove()`  doesn't specify any class to remove.
   Change to `.classList.remove('active')`
2. `list.classList.toggle('active');` will never toggle `active` class.  It will be the same as `list.classList.add('active');`

If you really want to toggle  `active` class  do

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#list > li').forEach( (list_el,_,all) =>
  {
  list_el.onclick =_=>
    {
    if ( list_el.classList.toggle('active') )
      all.forEach( li => li.classList.toggle('active', list_el===li ))
    }
  })
```

```css
#list > li {
  cursor : pointer;
  }
.active {
  color: crimson;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

lists.forEach(list => list.classList.remove("active"))

you don't need this part as toggle('active') will remove the class when you click twice

```js
const lists = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
lists.forEach(list => {
  list.addEventListener('click', () => {

    // remove the previous class active
    
    list.classList.toggle('active');

  });
});
```

```css
.list.active {
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
  <li class="list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
  <li class="list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
  <li class="list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
</ul>
```